# Programação Python (calculo de média com ações, caso média menor que valor definido)

Tags: python, if, else

Preciso da ajuda de vocês para resolver uma questão do meu curso de programação, estou com uma atividade inicial e não sei por onde continuar, preciso criar um programa que receba 2 notas, some e as divida por dois gerando a média. (consegui fazer isso) Agora preciso implementar o programa caso o aluno tenha a média menor que 6 o programa deverá solicitar que seja feito uma nova prova (consegui fazer até o print dessa mensagem caso o if seja menor que 6) só que depois dessa mensagem ele deverá dar as seguintes ações:

Ação 1 se a nota 3 for maior que a nota 1 substituir a nota 1 e fazer a soma e a divisão com as restantes.

Ação 2 se a nota 3 for maior que a nota 2 substituir a nota 2 e fazer a soma e a divisão com as restantes.

Ação 3 se a nota 3 for menor que as duas notas, exibir a mensagem de aluno reprovado.

Segue meu código, estou bem perdido para poder realizar essas ações.

```
def main ():    

  nome = input('Nome do Aluno: ')
  ra = input('RA do aluno: ')
  print('Inserir notas de "0 a 10.0"')
  nota1 = float(input('Prova 1: '))
  nota2 = float(input('Prova 2: '))
  media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2
    
  if media > 6.0:
        print('O aluno ' , nome, 'de RA' , ra, 'foi Aprovado com a média ', media)
  else:
        nota3 = float(input('Aluno não passou, favor insirir nota da prova 3: '))
      
      
        maior1 = nota3
    
        if maior1 < nota1:
            maior1 = nota1
        if maior1 < nota2:
            maior1 = nota2
    
        if maior1 == nota3:
            if nota1 >= nota2:
                maior2 = nota1
        else:
            maior2 = nota2
    
        if maior1 == nota2:
            if nota1 >= nota3:
                maior2 = nota1
        else:
            maior2 = nota3
    
        if maior1 == nota1:
            if nota2 >= nota3:
                maior2 = nota2
        else:
            maior2 = nota3
    
        media = (maior1 + maior2)/2
        if media>= 6.00:
                print('O aluno ', nome, 'de RA ', ra, 'foi Aprovado com a média ', media, )
    
        else:
            print('O aluno ', nome, 'de RA ', ra, 'foi Reprovado com a média ', media, )
main ()
```

Agradeço desde já a ajuda de vocês!

Comment: Creio que você inverteu as comparações em seus `if` com `nota3` e a última condição dever ser `if nota3 < nota1 and nota3 < nota2`

Comment: Criei mais algumas linhas de comando, mas continuo enfrentando problemas com o código. na parte da validação

Comment: No `else` não é para informar uma condição. Este `elif media<6:` não tem sentido porque sóserá executado se `media >= 6.0`.

Comment: Bom, dei uma olhada e não entendi o porquê da função, tenta tirar ela (se não for exigência do exercício); tem os sinais invertidos das condições, como já foi comentado; o primeiro print após a condição está com a terceira nota englobada e não vai ler, vai dar erro (digo pelo que sei até agora, apesar de ser iniciante); os 2 últimos prints são para a mesma coisa, tira um, ah e lembra de indentar na condição certa. Vê se dá certo aí.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de fazer é com o uso do elif.

```
def main():
nome = input('Nome do Aluno: ')
ra = input('RA do aluno: ')
print('Inserir notas de "0 a 10.0"')
nota1 = float(input('Prova 1: '))
nota2 = float(input('Prova 2: '))
media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2

if media > 6.0:
    print('O aluno ' , nome, 'de RA' , ra, 'foi Aprovado com a média ', media)
else:
    nota3 = float(input('Aluno não passou, favor insirir nota da prova 3: '))

    #Com o uso do elif fica melhor de fazer, ja que ele só vai execultar quando o if for falso.
    if nota2 > nota1 < nota3:
        nota1 = nota3
    elif nota3 > nota2:
        nota2 = nota3

    media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2

    if media >= 6.00:
        print('O aluno ', nome, 'de RA ', ra, 'foi Aprovado com a média ', media, )

    else:
        print('O aluno ', nome, 'de RA ', ra, 'foi Reprovado com a média ', media, )

main()
```